# How to detect div overflow in a bunch of same div classes Using JavaScript (and jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, detect

I have 31 div with the same class ".cal". Is there any way to detect each div and if one (or many other) div do have overflow, the browser automatically add a html content remind users that this div is overflowed?

I know I should check clientHeight

Comment: Detection would be done with `$(".cal")` but how do you define overflowed? Should the DIVs have a maximum height?

Comment: Could you not just check the CSS?

Comment: One way to detect overflow is to test if scroll bars have been added. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, what I meant was when the scroll bar has shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery:

```js
$(".cal").each(function(i){
    if ($(this).css("overflow") === "hidden") {
        $(this).html("Overflow");
    }
});
```

**EDIT** @JoJo explained me what I’ve missed from your description. So just put an inner wrapper into your `.cal` div and get height and width of the wrapper instead. If inner wrapper is larger than your `.cal` then the block is overflown. Proof of concept on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaJu7/1/)

Comment: Then have my +1 for your answer @JoJo :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know jQuery, so here is the Prototype solution. I'm sure it's easy to convert to jQuery. The idea is to check the full height of the contents.  If it exceeds the clipped height, then it is considered overflown. We add a "overflowError" class in this case. Perhaps this class will reveal the "show more" button via CSS.

```
$$('.cal').each(
 function(div) {
  div.setStyle({overflow: 'visible'});
  var fullHeight = div.getHeight();
  div.setStyle({overflow: 'hidden'});
  if (div.getHeight() < fullHeight) {
   div.addClassName('overflowError');
  }
 }
);
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant! However even though I defined overflowError, the style just won't show up even though the div is overflown.

Comment: Fixed. The inequality was switched from > to <.